# X be locally compact Hausdorff space. If $x\in U$ for some open set $U$, then there exists a open precompact set included in $U$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

The following is from *Measure Theory, 2nd edition*, by Cohn.

I understand the proof of:

> **Proposition 7.1.2** *Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $K$ and $L$ be disjoint compact subsets of $X$. Then there are disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subseteq U$ and $L \subseteq V$.*

But then I don't understand a passage in the following proof:

> **Proposition 7.1.3** *Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, let $x$ be a point in $X$, and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Then $x$ has an open neighborhood whose closure is compact and is included in $U$.*
>
> *Proof.* Since $X$ is locally compact, there is an open neighborhood of $x$, say $W$, whose closure is compact. By replacing $W$ with $W \cap U$, we can assume that $W$ is included in $U$. The difficulty is that $\overline{W}$ may extend outside $U$. Use Proposition 7.1.2. to choose disjoint open sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ that separate the compact sets $\{ x \}$ and $\overline{W} - W$. The closure of $V_1 \cap W$ is then compact and included in $W$ and hence in $U$; thus $V_1 \cap W$ is the required open neighborhood of $x$.

My question is: Why is the closure of $V_1\cap W$ included in $W$? I just couldn't figure it out!

---

My solution: $\overline{V_1\cap W}\subseteq W$ otherwise there exists $x\in\overline{V_1\cap W}$ such that $x\in \overline{W}-W$ so that $x\in V_2$. But $V_2$ is open so there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq V_2$. This shows that $B(x,r)\cap V_1=\emptyset$ so that $x\notin \overline{V_1}$, a contradiction.

Comment: What does “included” mean?

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you!

Comment: @azif00 I think it means $V_1\cap W \subseteq W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct intuition for what is happening, you just need to be careful as you are dealing with general topological spaces, not necessarily metric spaces. I am sure that your book spells out the difference between these two notions and you should review it: metric spaces are a special case of the more general notion of topological spaces (moreover – but this is a finer point than you need – there is no relation between being metrizable and locally compact for a topological space, since you can have metric spaces which are not locally compact and locally compact Hausdorff spaces which are not metrizable). In particular, your solution is essentially correct, you just need to avoid mentioning open balls (there is no metric, hence doing so doesn't make sense): $V_2$ is open and disjoint from $V_1$, thus $x\notin \overline{V_1}$, a contradiction.